# <select> not working in Phonegap app on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on Phonegap app for Android and iOS. Most of the stuff works pretty well but I'm experiencing a problem with `<select>` tag. It's enhanced with jQuery mobile and on that version of Android when the appropriate div is clicked / tapped the options are not showing up. They show up when I do two clicks / taps:

1. on a div containing `<select>`
2. on a area above the div

In that scenario options show up and when selected change event is fired and code bind to it is executed.

I found these two android issues:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10280 and 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721

I have tried the workarounds mentioned there but they don't change anything. I still have to do two clicks but it's not the behavior I'm after. I only need one click.

Issue exists only on Android 2.3.3 and I think on older versions too. On iOS and newer Androids everything works perfectly fine.

I'm struggling with this issue whole day and tried everything.

Any help, tips would be heavily appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: hi,were u able to get around this  issue?

Comment: I'm checking if it's an android platform and if yes, I'm using different template without <select> in it. I'm building drop down myself and I also have to handle click by myself. It's basically a div with ul list showing / hiding when certain element is clicked

Comment: update: on android 3.2.x there is a problem with the solution from my previous comment, user has to click somewhere outside the selected item to get it working

Comment: you should add data-native-menu="false"

Comment: probably element height issue. check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33922023/3619617

Answer (score 7):

Did You try adding data-native-menu="false" attribute to the select menu.

Example:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" data-theme="b" data-native-menu="false" >
    <option value="">Please specify ...</option>
    <option value="option1">Male</option>
    <option value="option2">Female</option>
    <option value="option3">Undisclosed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what solved my problem. In android 2.3.x I've set `z-index` on select box to `~1000`(far above other elements) and it solved the problem. Apparently native browser is messing up the "layers". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem with android 2.3 and a JavaScript generated select box, my solution for this was using jQuery to focus the element once it was rendered and every time it was rendered again (even if using $.SELECT.show()).

After doing $("#element").focus() the select box behaves normally again, its both clickable and updates after selecting a new option.

Comment: will try that when client asks for an update of the app :) thanks for sharing your solution

Comment: This is one crazy bug. Thanks a lot for the solution, it's a real lifesaver when facing a client who can't/won't update their devices. I tried lots of other suggestions before this one, including getting rid of ```position:fixed``` and elements with ```opacity``` set, none of those made a difference for me on Android 2.3.6. This one did the job.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i realized the problem was because i had used data-position="fixed" property for the heading of the page which contained the select element. when i removed data-position="fixed" from my heading, heading was not fixed surely, but got rid of this annoying problem of selects not being 'clicked'. hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The only way it worked for me was adding this on my jQuery script:

```
$('select').click(function () {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me so far except since my dropdown's not available at time the script is loaded, I use 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of your suggests with no luck. 
What i've ended up with is not the best solution, but it's better than the alternative, if nothing else will update the select box.
I did it with jQuery like this:

```
$(".select_box").change(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".select_box").show();
});
```

Bum, updated.

Please remember, that this is only a solution if nothing else will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `div` page is not inside another `div`. It should look like:

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    ...
  </div>
 </body>
```

NOT like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    ...
    <div data-role="page">
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I had exactly the same problem using a `select` with `data-native-menu="true"` and all worked fine once I removed that extra `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this question was published two years ago, but just in case someone face this problem today, as I did recently:

I had the same behaviour as the one you tell.
The problem I had was with a div that appeared as a header and had the attribute data-role="header" and data-position="fixed". There's a bug in jquery mobile that causes a number of strange issues in Android 2.2/2.3 (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/fixed-toolbars/).

I fixed that error removing 'data-position="fixed"' from the header and adding a custom class with the following code:

```
.custom-header{
    position: fixed !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.