# Dropdown not showing in popup (jQuery Mobile 1.2 + Cordova 2.2) on Android 2.x

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, popup

There is a fix for the issue that the dropdown is not working on Android 2.x & Phonegap :
[<select> not working in Phonegap app on Android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243477/select-not-working-in-phonegap-app-on-android-2-3-3)

However, if I use the select box in a popup of jQuery Mobile 1.2 then that fix is not working.

I'm using Cordova 2.2.0

Anybody any ideas how to get a select box working in a popup for Android 2.x

Comment: you should add data-native-menu="false"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change z-index of the drop down element to ~1000, way above all other elements.