# PhoneGap Select Boxes on Android Misbehaving

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, drop-down-menu

I have select boxes in my app which appear properly, are selectable (ie: one can click them, and apparently make a selection), but don't behave the way they are supposed to:

After clicking an item in the list, the name/value of that option is not populated in the form.

I've found lots of stackoverflow questions/answers about select-box issues, but none of them seem to be exactly my problem. Nevertheless, I have tried these suggestions without success, including putting a high z-index value in the select box, adding some -webkit specific values to the CSS, etc.

I've tried:

[<select> box not displaying on Android in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523309/select-box-not-displaying-on-android-in-phonegap)

[<select> not working in Phonegap app on Android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243477/select-not-working-in-phonegap-app-on-android-2-3-3)

[PhoneGap build webkit-appearance no drop down arrow for select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738203/phonegap-build-webkit-appearance-no-drop-down-arrow-for-select-tag)

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6992

https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/threads/451455/phonegap-select-box-is-not-working

There is no jQuery involved.

Is there something I'm missing regarding select boxes?

An example-- the HTML:

```
<select name="people0" id="people0" onfocus="isDirty=1" style="display:inline-block;min-width:150px;" data-native-menu="true">
        <option value="0">Choose Person</option>
            <option value="15098">Desjardins, Emily</option>
        <option value="17304">Hulley, Patrick</option>
        <option value="1">Silver, Jason</option>
</select>
```

The CSS:

```
select{
    /* Suggestions found: having trouble with not being able to select items: */
    -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index:1000 !important;
}
```

UPDATE November 8:

I have found a terrible work-around -- but at least you can select options. When the HTML response comes from the server, I check to see if there are select elements in it, and attach event listeners to them if there are:

```
var allSelectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i=0; i < allSelectElements.length; i++) {
    allSelectElements[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        alert('initiating touch');
        this.focus;
    }, false);
}
```

I wish someone could solve this once-and-for-all. :-/

Comment: Sometimes it seems to work if while the select box is in view, I drag my finger to scroll the greyed-background, or if I touch and hold the option for a moment before letting go.

Comment: An interesting aspect of this was found-- not by adding focus on click/touchend, but by sending an alert box on touchstart... only way I can get it to work now:      var allSelectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for (var i=0; i < allSelectElements.length; i++) {
      allSelectElements[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
       alert('initiating touch');

      }, false);
     }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved using similar code:

```
var allSelectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i=0; i < allSelectElements.length; i++) {
    allSelectElements[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        //This is the important line
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, great job!

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for me was adding a jQuery trick:

```
$('select').click(function () {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: I write in plain old javascript, but I'll try something similar.

Comment: Note my hack above-- only way I could get it to work. (I'm not using jQuery)... I programmatically add an event listener to selectboxes so when touching them, an alert appears. Somehow this allows the selection of an option.

Comment: It works, but it's awful -- surely there has to be a better way. :-(