# cordova application "Select" dropdown not working in iOS9

Tags: cordova

Hi My cordova app contains a simple select dropdown Which contain options as 1,2,3,4.
 When I open My app in iPad Full view and click on Select dropdown, its opening and am able to select an option in it . 
 But when I open My app in iOS9 split view(33% or 50%) and click on this "Select" dropdown, select dropdown is taking total split screen width and height and its not responding.Any help would be appreciated. I am not using any external plugins like jquery mobile etc... Thanks In advance

Comment: You need to post some more information such as what framework is your app using (e.g. Ionic, jQuery Mobile, Meteor), HTML/JS showing how you define the `<select>`. Also maybe a screenshot illustrating what "taking total split screen" means.

Comment: First Thanks for your fast response.I created cordova application, added iOS platform and my  index.html  contains below select dropdown code. <select id="cityList">
                     <option>1</option>
                     <option>2</option>
                     <option>3</option>
                     <option>4</option>
                </select>

Comment: Sorry I am not able to add image or screen shot

Comment: In the question please, and remember to format your question properly ;)

Comment: @DaveAlden  could you please check the attachment I have added in the below link.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9689

Comment: Yep, does look like a bug. It may be that UIWebView which Cordova uses on iOS 9 hasn't been optimized for split-view. You could try using [WKWebView](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView) plugin to see if that helps, since it is the preferred WebView since iOS 8 (Safari uses it)

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden.Will try using WKWebView

Comment: @DaveAlden still same issue.Any other suggestions please

Comment: Sounds like a bug either in Cordova or iOS 9.0, related to split view. My only other suggestion is try to reproduce it in a web page in Safari on iOS 9 to figure out if bug is in Cordova or iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issue while trying to show select dropdown in a popup. Select dropdown was visible but it was not responding to click events. The page height was less than what the popup was covering. After adding min-height to body tag, "select" was functional again. Below is sample css that I'm using.

```
body{
    min-height:300px;
}

.popup-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
}
```

Hope this helps.